# Present one amount field into 2 fields and present as one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have some records in the following way:

[image]

Have to insert the records in a table in the following way:

[image]

What approach I should follow to get this record in SQL Server?

I have created a query which is getting me the Deliveramt and ReceiveAmt int separate result set like:

[image]

Then doing inner join between the two is only giving me multiplied values as I need to sum them up to retrieve the correct result later.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union them, then aggregate.

```
SELECT Bcode
, SUM(DeliverAmt) AS DeliverAmt
, SUM(ReceiveAmt) AS ReceiveAmt
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      DeliverBcode AS Bcode
    , Amount AS DeliverAmt
    , 0 AS ReceiveAmt
    FROM YourTable

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT ReceiveBcode, 0, Amount
    FROM YourTable
) q
GROUP BY Bcode
ORDER BY Bcode
```